# Foreach don't get multiple repetitions

Tags: php, for-loop, foreach

It runs thru an array, checking the repetitions, keeping just the unique session_id ( and that works with no issue at all) , the problem is that each time it finds a repeated unique ID it should replace the second date with   $result[$i-1][3] = $val['date']; , allowing us to control the time between the first sessionID and last one ( creating the time of the session ).

However when it finds the first repetition, it keeps, and don't keep any other ( we can have for example 10 repetitions.

Foreach code

```
   foreach($parsed['results'] as $val){
        if ($i>0) {
            $y = $i - 1;
        }
         if($i==0){
            $result[] = [
                $val['source'],
                $val['session_id'],
                $val['date'],
                $val['date'],
            ];
           
            $i++;
        }else if ($val['session_id']!=0){
          $y=0;
          
           for ($j=1;$j<=count($val);$j++)
           
               {
       
                if($val['session_id']==$result[$i-1][1]    )
                {
                $result[$i-1][3] = $val['date']; 
                break;
                
                }
                else{
                   
            
                    $result[] = [
                        $val['source'],
                        $val['session_id'],
                        $val['date'],
                        $val['date'],
                   
                     ];
         
             
            }
            $i++;
        }
     
    
}
    else{}
    }
```

Result

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => Product#0 [1] => ripkd6im70d7qn [2] => 2020-07-06T23:58:22+00:00 [3] => 2020-07-06T23:58:22+00:00 ) [1] => Array ( [0] => Product#1 [1] => 89m1s1qgleelo [2] => 2020-07-06T23:58:20+00:00 [3] => 2020-07-06T23:58:19+00:00 ) [2] => Array ( [0] => Product#2 [1] => 5rpf097c3n7q4[2] => 2020-07-06T23:55:49+00:00 [3] => 2020-07-06T23:55:47+00:00 ) [3] => Array ( [0] => Product#3 [1] => 3p04fkejncd [2] => 2020-07-06T23:46:13+00:00 [3] => 2020-07-06T23:46:11+00:00 ) [4] => Array ( [0] => Product#4 [1] => 7qa1p9pmti1mb2r [2] => 2020-07-06T23:45:00+00:00 [3] => 2020-07-06T23:44:59+00:00 )
```

Comment: Can you share the content of `$parsed['results']` ?

Comment: the content of $parsed results it's the result mentioned on the end of the post.

Comment: The $parsed itself has the following structure :  this is the position 0 of the array:
 Array ( [0] => Array ( [event_id] => c2Vzc2lvbl9k = [session_id] => ripkd6im70d7qn [log_id] => [date] => 2020-07-06T23:58:22+00:00 [key] => INTENT_END_RESPONDED [value] => - [id_content] => [source] => Product#0 [user_type] => 0 [env] => production [user_question] => )

Comment: I thought that it was what you wanted. So now I'm not sure what output you want :)

Comment: The output is alright however each time it finds a session id repeated it should replaced the date, however it doesn't . So it sessionid1,prod1,date,date , second run if its same sessionid, only replaces the second date in the array where that session id is, if its a new add in the array the 4 in a newline